# Use Mirror modifier but keep the UVs

Tags: modifiers, uv, uv-image-editor, mirror, mirror-modifier

During my project I discovered that something was not mirrored properly, the problem is that I had already done texture and UVs for everything, so if I cut in half and put a mirror modifier it puts the UVs on top of each other.
I tried to save a copy of the previous mesh and do copy uvs, but it just tells me that the half I mirrored failed.
Anyone have an idea how to fix this?